# SIM900 and Phone Numbers

Tags: arduino, at-commands, sim900

How do I add a phone number to the SIM900? Can I add a phone number to the SIM900? Assuming I can, would I send the phone number through the AT Commands or the actual SIM card? I don't know how to write to a SIM card without another phone, so I am lost on how to write it standalone. The purpose of this is that I want to add my phone number to another device that uses Arduino and an SIM900 breakout. It is a project that could use that "phone" to receive calls and SMS and etc.

Comment: A phone doesn't have a number without a SIM card.

Comment: As Matt says, take the SIM out of your phone to test the SIM900. You can get SIM's for pay-as-you-go phones anywhere or get bulk SIMS from a service provider. I get them from T-Mobile for one customer. Verizon doesn't use SIMS and AT&T is impossible to deal with. T-Mobile will send a rep out to see what you need.

Comment: Yes well then how do I add the phone number to the new SIM? Do I just put it into my phone and then setup the number as before? Then once it is in do I transfer it to the SIM900?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't write a phone number to the SIM900.

Your cellular service provider writes the phone number, along with other account information, to a SIM card.  You connect the SIM card to the device.

You will need a separate phone number for the SIM900 - unless you want to pull the sim card out of your phone every time you want to use it.

Even if you could program a new SIM card to have exactly the same information as the one in your phone, your provider would detect that and be very unhappy with you.